# ODBC FDW para PostgreSQL con Access

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

alguien a realizado la conexión de tablas foráneas usando ODBC FDW para consumir tablas de una base de datos ACCESS

Tengo esto:

```
CREATE EXTENSION odbc_fdw;

CREATE SERVER mi_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER odbc_fdw
OPTIONS (
  drivername 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)',
  servername 'datos' 
);

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
  SERVER mi_server
  OPTIONS (
    odbc_UID 'postgres',
    odbc_PWD ''
  );

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE public.test
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombres character varying
    )
    SERVER mi_server
OPTIONS (
odbc_DATABASE 'test',
  table_name 'test' 
)

OBTENGO ESTE ERROR 
ERROR:  Connecting to driver
Estado SQL: 58000
```

Ya tengo configurado el DSN, lo hice como DSN de Usuario y de Sistema y da el mismo error.